# full authentication is required to access this resource angular sprig boot

Tags: angular, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have some problem with security cofigure. I have web application which build on spring boot , and used angular 7 for UI. I created security, configured it, and all was ok. In angular i used proxy , which transform urls from "localhost:4200" in "localhost:9501".

```
{
"/api/*":{
    "target": "http://localhost:9501",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"

}
```

}

And in backends side i have start controller.

```
@Controller
public class StartController {

  @RequestMapping({"/ui/**"})
  public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
  }
 }
```

But when I to integrated angular in my spring boot application i got problem. When i wrote in "(/* *).permitAll()" , everything okey and it's work. But when i tried "(/api/auth/**).permittAll()" i had a trouble "full authentication is required to access this resource".

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
               // .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```